# setEnabled() and requestFocusWindow() not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, jinternalframe

so I searched online and tried things and common functions to focus on window but whenever I click on Exit button, it won't return to main JFrame.

When I remove the this.setEnabled(true), it does it but what I really wanted to do is to disable the main JFrame when jButton9 is clicked and show the JInternalFrame. Then close the JInternalFrame when Exit button is clicked.

I tried the instructions on this website http://www.coderanch.com/t/334157/GUI/java/JInternalFrame-Focus

Here's what I've done so far. I'd appreciate any help.

[image]

```
private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                         

    AddTo_Assigned_Subjects_InternalFrame.setVisible(true);
    this.setEnabled(false);
    AddTo_Assigned_Subjects_InternalFrame.requestFocusInWindow();

}                                        

private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    AddTo_Assigned_Subjects_InternalFrame.setVisible(false);
    AddTo_Assigned_Subjects_InternalFrame.dispose();


}
```

"this" is my MainFrame
"Add_To_Assigned_Subjects_InternalFrame" holds the exit button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Form Javadoc on requestFocusWindow()

This method cannot be used to set the focus owner to no Component at all. Use KeyboardFocusManager.clearGlobalFocusOwner() instead.

The focus behavior of this method can be implemented uniformly across platforms, and thus developers are strongly encouraged to use this method over requestFocus when possible. Code which relies on requestFocus may exhibit different focus behavior on different platforms.